# Создание второго конструктора с помощью classmethod python

Tags: python, ооп

Задача состоит в создании второго конструктора для класса.
Первый конструктор принимает на вход параметры: имя, возраст, жанры, рейтинг:

```
def __init__(self, name, age, rate = 0, genres = None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.rate = rate
        self.genres = set(genres)
```

Второй конструктор должен принимать на вход такие параметры: имя, возраст, фильмы.
Я предполагаю, что он должен быть реализован с помощью фабричного метода:

```
@classmethod
def second_constructor(cls, name, age, movies=[])
    genres = set(movies.keys()) #if movies else []
    rate = sum(movies.values())/len(movies.values())
    return cls(name, age, rate = 0, genres = [])
```

В зависимости от того сколько было передано аргументов при создании экземпляра класса должны использоваться разные конструкторы.

Пример:

```
n = HollywoodStar("oleg", 21, {"movie1":1, "movie2":2})
print(HollywoodStar.second_constructor(n)) #должен использоваться второй конструктор
n = HollywoodStar("oleg", 21, 1, ["action", "comedy"]) #первый конструктор
```

Так как изначально срабатывает первый конструктор, то при попытке создания экземпляра класса с 3 переданными аргументами появляется ошибка. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вы что-то странное пытаетесь сделать. Сначала в вашем втором конструкторе вы вычисляете переменные genres и rate, а потом вообще никак их не используете. Потом вы почему-то вызываете метод second_constructor, который согласно определению принимает от двух до трёх аргументов, но вы передаёте ему только один аргумент n.

Comment: Плюс у вас у аргумента movies значение по умолчанию - список, но дальше вы обращаетесь к movies.keys() и movies.values(), что тоже приведёт к ошибке.

Comment: Ну и непонятно, что вы имеете в виду под "фабричным методом", если этот шаблон предполагает существование класса и подкласса, а в вашем коде есть только один класс.